gradle defines the root project incorrectly
error 

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'weather-measure'.
> Project with path ':weather-entity' could not be found in root project 'weather-measure'.

gradle defines the root project incorrectly. in fact, the root project is 'weather-microservices'
project structure

weather-microservices (root)
├── weather-measure (dependent on weather-entity)
|   |
|   |__ src
|   |__build.gradle
|   |__settings.gradle
|    
|
|__ weather-entity
|   |
|   |__ src
|   |__ build.gradle
|   |__settings.gradle
|   
├── build.gradle
├── settings.gradle

bulid.gradle (weather-measure)

dependencies {
    implementation project(':weather-entity')
}

settings.gradle (weather-measure)

rootProject.name = 'weather-measure'

settings.gradle (weather-microservices)

rootProject.name = 'weather-microservices'
include 'weather-measure'
include 'weather-entity'

a little bit more about error
Build file 'C:\Users\umafa\IdeaProjects\weather-microservices\weather-measure\build.gradle' line: 30

A problem occurred evaluating root project 'weather-measure'.
> Project with path ':weather-entity' could not be found in root project 'weather-measure'.

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'weather-measure'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:137)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:140)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.code.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:425)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:406)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:46)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:27)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:407)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$2(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:430)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:360)


Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.

i cleaned the project with gradle
and i rewrote rootProject.name in modules to "weather-microservices"
and i tried to delete settings.gradle in modules,
but it dosen't help.
I can give more details if you need

Only the root project of a build should have a settings.gradle[.kts] file. Remove the settings.gradle files from the subproject directories. You say that "doesn't help", but it's the correct thing to do. There may be more problems though.

Slaw thanks, it works! after deleting settings.gradle in modules, i was getting some error related to kotlin, i just disabled the kotlin plugin in intellij idea settings
